# Matlab DLL Integration via C++ or VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, matlab, dll

I haven't found a solution to my problem, because of limited knowledge about dll Libraries.
I am using Matlab (R2017a) to integrate communication to a device through a dll, which is provided by the manufacturer ([files](http://www.systec.de/index.php?id=1478&L=1) - Xemo-DLL (64Bit) mit Header-Dateien (2.40)).

As far as I understand there is precompiled .dll in C and a header File in C++, beside a VB and VB.NET wrapper.

Question is: What is the best way to integrate the dll into Matlab?

A) I tried loadlibrary(XemoDll). It throws a lot of errors, iostream wasn't found. So I added extern "C" {} to the whole file, which created new errors at every function definition. Where do I have to insert it?

B) I tried to add NET.addAssembly(path\XemoDll.vb) of the VB.NET library. There is a Module with all wrapper functions. Matlabs gives the error "assembly manifest missing" Source: mscorlib.

Comment: AFAIK you have to write a matlab wrapper for the DLL, this can be done e.g. with  the MEX compiler integrated in matlab. It compiles c/C++ code to function that can be used within matlab

Comment: loadlibrary itself only supports header files that can be parsed by a c compiler. iostream is c++ and not c so this will not work directly. write a wrapper dll that exports a plain c interface

Answer (score 0):

I found a [Tutorial](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm) on loading Dlls with the LoadLibrary() command from windows.h, and got it working.

I use a a DllInterface_mex function that gets the function name and calls the approriate function in the Dll.